# c# helix-toolkit, how to open examples from source

Tags: c#, reference, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

Hello I am kinda new and my question is rather basic.
I want to use the helix toolkit for some visualization.
I downloaded the source, but whenever I open the examples or projects, a lot
of the references do not work. If I click on the reference, for example SharpDX there is no path to the dll.

However it would be a lot of work to change all the references by hand, because there are so many examples and different projects. Does anyone know the reason why it does not work?

I just downloaded the whole helix toolkit from github and started different examples, but the references never seem to work.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm new too but found that if you open the example browser solution, go to the nuget console and:

Install-Package HelixToolkit   <-this resolves most references

also do the same for naudio  <-a couple more

build the dll for HelixToolkit.Wpf.Input (already setup just open the project, build and point at it from add reference)

Add the references for PropertyTools from somewhere under examples (search "PropertyTools" under where ever you extracted the zip to, you'll find the Dll's)

mine were in C:\Users\scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\helix\helix-toolkit-master\Source\Examples\WPF\ExampleBrowser\packages\PropertyTools.Wpf.2015.2.0\lib\net45

Comment: you will need to save the helix projects before adding the nuget libs.  Also, you'll need to: install-package helixtoolkit.wpf in both the example browser and helixtoolkit.wpf.input before building.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, right mouse button on you project in the Solution Explorer and choose Manage Nuget Packages, choose browse (right top), type helixtookit, you will see all the packages you will need. Install the ones you need.

Good luck.

i.konuk